# jQuery's ajax() does not work if jQuery is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery's `post()` and `get()` but they are **not working**.
I do not have HTML so I am loading jQuery this way:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Seems like it is successfully loaded. Checked using `window.jQuery` in the console.

Right after I create a button:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.id = 'gogogo';
var txt = document.createTextNode("Go");
btn.appendChild(txt);
document.body.insertBefore(btn, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Button successfully created.

Right after this I have the desired `post()`:

```
$("#gogogo").click(function () {
    var txt = '123';
    $.post("/users", {qwe: txt}, function(result){
            alert(result);
    });
});
```

But **nothing happens** at all. NET section in FireBug remains empty while clicking on the button.

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Event delegation is required. Best way to set up events to dynamic elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on learn here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on` event of jQuery, As you are dynamically creating element i.e `event delegation.`

For ex.

```
$(document).on("click","#gogogo",function () {
    alert("Inside #gogogo event handler");
    var txt = '123';
    $.post("/users", {qwe: txt}, function(result){
            alert(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: what you see on console? Put a alert updated in my answer to see are you inside the event handler or not.

Comment: The console is empty and nothing happens.

Comment: did the alert show up  alert("Inside #gogogo event handler");

Comment: it should work. check if DOM has button with id.remove post call. just see if the handler alert or console.log is getting printed or not. put console.log also. sometimes alert doesn't show up.